# Python create SharedMemory instance using existing buffer (bytes from marshal.dumps())

Tags: python, buffer, marshalling, shared-memory

I would like to create an instance of `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory` passing from outside the buffer to use to hold the data.

My use case is the following:

```py
import marshal

from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory


data = {'foo' 1, 'bar': 'some text'}
data_bytes = marshal.dumps(data)
shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=len(data_bytes))

for i,b in enumerate(data_bytes):
    shm.buf[i] = b
```

As you can see I need to serialise some data (to later share it across multiple processes). The snippet above uses twice the memory that is actually needed since the serialised data stored in the `data_bytes` bytes variable needs to be copied inside the SharedMemory buffer (which also takes a considerable amount since in my use case the dimension of `data` is 1 GB).

The only non-viable solution I have found so far is to guess how much space the serialised data will take, allocate enough space in a `SharedMemory` instance and have `marshal` write on it, e.g.

```py
shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=BIG_ENOUGHT_SIZE)
marshal.dump(data, shm.buf.obj)
```

However, if my guess is too low, `marshal.dump(data, shm.buf.obj)` (correctly) throws an error because there is not enough space to write the serialised data.

Comment: What's wrong with "allocate enough space ... and have `marshal` write on it"?

Comment: Since I don't know a priori the size of the deserialized data I have to guess to set the value of `BIG_ENOUGHT_SIZE`; if I choose a value too low `dump()` (correctly) throws an error because there is not enought space. Maybe this is unclear in my question. Maybe this is unclear in my question, I am going to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a buffer object to a SharedMemory instance seems to be impossible at the moment (Python 3.9).
The best I have achieved is to use slice assignment to copy the data (which is way faster than using a for loop, if you are using CPython).

```
import marshal

from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory


data = {'foo' 1, 'bar': 'some text'}
data_bytes = marshal.dumps(data)
data_bytes_len = len(data_bytes)

shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=data_bytes_len)

# 'shm' may allocate more memory than the actual requested amount
# hence we must specify the length of data_bytes in the slice assignment
shm.buf[:data_bytes_len] = data_bytes
```